# ISO String to Datetime in ruby invalid date?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to a date time object. The string looks like this

`"2016-06-16T23:26:25.252Z"`

I have been trying to convert it using `DateTime.strptime(str,"'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z")` but gives invalid date error.

Do any of you know the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: `DateTime.iso8601("2016-06-16T23:26:25.252Z")` is less fuss.

Answer (score 3):

You put an extra quotation mark in the string.

```
str = "2016-06-16T23:26:25.252Z"
DateTime.strptime(str,"'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z") #=> ArgumentError: invalid date
DateTime.strptime(str,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z")  #=> #<DateTime: 2016-06-16T23:26:25+00:00 ((2457556j,84385s,252000000n),+0s,2299161j)>
                      ^^^
```